# mySQL : Query based on user form filled preference

Tags: mysql

An answer might already be available in SO, I'm looking at guidance for my search (I don't know if it's a CASE WHEN or Order BY...)

I have a weekdays BD filled with available schedules:

```
+____+__________+________+________+_________+___________+__________+________+
| id | Saturday | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
+____+__________+________+________+_________+___________+__________+________+
| 1  |    OFF   |   OFF  |   8-4  |   8-4   |    8-4    |   8-4    |  4-0   |     
| 2  |    4-0   |   OFF  |   OFF  |   8-4   |    8-4    |   8-4    |  8-4   |
| 3  |    4-0   |   OFF  |   OFF  |   8-4   |    8-4    |   8-4    |  4-0   |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

User will fill a form of schedule preference with a priority:

```
Priority 1: Saturday = OFF  
Priority 2: sunday = OFF  
Priority 3: Monday = 8-4  
Priority 4: Tuesday= 8-4  
Priority 5: Wednesday = 8-4  
Priority 6: Thursday = 8-4  
Priority 7: Friday = 8-4
```

Now if I can't match all 7 priorities, I need to check if I can meet his first 6 priorities, if I can't meet his first 6 I try to meet his first 5 and so on until I find a match.

In our case above, I cannot meet priority 7 so best match would be schedule id 1 (matching priority 1 to 6).

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd run multiple queries separately. So that first one checks for match for all n prorities and the subsequent check for n-1, n-2 ... priorities. The first match you get would be the best match. The overall logic is simplified and the performance hit should not be significant

.. or if you definitely prefer a one query approach you might write a query building loop that will built you something like:

```
  select 1 as priority, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday FROM weekdays AS all_priorities WHERE {Priority1} AND {Priority2} AND {Priority3} AND{Priority4} AND{Priority5} AND   {Priority6} AND   {Priority7}
UNION
select 2 as priority, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday FROM weekdays AS all_priorities WHERE {Priority1} AND {Priority2} AND {Priority3} AND {Priority4} AND{Priority5} AND   {Priority6} 
UNION
select 3 as priority, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday FROM weekdays AS all_priorities WHERE {Priority1} AND {Priority2} AND {Priority3} AND{Priority4} AND {Priority5} 
UNION
select 4 as priority, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday FROM weekdays AS all_priorities WHERE {Priority1} AND {Priority2} AND {Priority3} AND {Priority4} 
UNION
select 5 as priority, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday FROM weekdays AS all_priorities WHERE {Priority1} AND{Priority2} AND {Priority3}
UNION
select 6 as priority, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday FROM weekdays AS all_priorities WHERE {Priority1} AND{Priority2} 
UNION
select 7 as priority, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday FROM weekdays AS all_priorities WHERE {Priority1}
ORDER BY priority DESC
```

Comment: Thank you @Jarek, your answer was my initial thinking but I thought maybe there was a simpler way of doing it. TY